# Silent Printing in asp.net with page range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, process, acrobat

Is it possible that I can silent print then input the page range(via codebehind) rather than printing the whole document like the code below?

```
    Dim infoPrint As New ProcessStartInfo()
        infoPrint.Arguments = "\" & rcbPrinters.SelectedItem.Text & "\"
        infoPrint.FileName = Session("strPath") 
        infoPrint.CreateNoWindow = True
        infoPrint.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        infoPrint.UseShellExecute = True
        infoPrint.Verb = "Print"
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(infoPrint)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000)
        Dim Process1 As New Process
        For Each prc As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("AcroRd32")
            prc.Kill()
        Next
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just used this function by extracting the pages then saving it as a new file then printing that file
http://forums.asp.net/t/1630140.aspx